# Should a LoggingHandler log?

Tags: python, logging

I wrote a custom log handler that has a config file and uses a service on the network. Now I'm wondering if it should itself log.

Pro:

- Everyone should log, it helps track errors, especially when you're relying on resources that can easily fail (config file, network service)

Contra:

- In the case of a logging handler, there is the potential of creating an infinite loop: Logging is not possible -> log message emitted -> logging handler tries to log -> logging not possible -> ...

Answer (score 1):

A LoggingHandker is a piece of software like any other, so it should be able to log like any other software. There are some problems though.

1. You can’t log normal logging operations because that will create infinite recursion. You have to be very careful if you want to log “1000 lines logged”, “2000 lines logged” etc. because for that to work logging needs to be reentrant.
2. If the first line in your logging manager initialisation code is LOG("initialising logging manager") then you can see how this is a problem. I’ve seen this solved by a logging manager collecting all log strings in an array of strings until the logging manager is fully running, and then dumping the contents of that array.
3. You need some common sense. If logging can be turned off and on then you log that you are going to turn it off before you turn it off, and you log that it was turned on first thing after you turn it on. If you can select which subsystems to log, you’d log any change to this whether the logging manager is turned on or not.
4. Here’s the real problem. You don’t log for fun. You log to find out what went wrong if something doesn’t work. You’d want to log the logging manager in case it doesn’t work. But if it doesn’t work, how is it going to log? That’s what you might want to think about.